# DAX IF Statement Can't Use Table Column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following DAX expression:

```
Students_Who_Viewed = var max_report_date = TOPN(1,DISTINCT(table_a_Historical[ReportDate]),table_a_Historical[ReportDate])
var last_week_report_date = max_report_date - 2
/////
var this_week_student_viewed = CALCULATE(
    SUM(table_a_Historical[CntViewedByStudent_CY]),
    KEEPFILTERS(table_a_Historical[ReportDate] = max_report_date)
    )
/////
var last_week_student_viewed = CALCULATE(
    SUM(table_a_Historical[CntViewedByStudent_CY]),
    KEEPFILTERS(table_a_Historical[ReportDate] = last_week_report_date)
    )
/////
var students_viewed_wow_change = COALESCE(this_week_student_viewed,0) - COALESCE(last_week_student_viewed,0)
/////
RETURN

IF (
    **table_a_Historical[exempt_status_cy] = "exempt" || table_a_Historical[exempt_status_py],**
    "N/A",
    IF (
        students_viewed_wow_change > 0 //This means views this week is more than last week.
        ,1
        ,IF (
            students_viewed_wow_change < 0 //This means there were less views this week than last week
            ,-1
            ,0 //This value will be used if there is no change in views this week relative to last week.
            )
         )
    )
```

In the part surrounded by **, I keep getting an error message. Those columns are valid in that table. Why is this?

Comment: Can you try like... min(table_a_Historical[exempt_status_cy])

Comment: That did it, apparently it has to be some sort of aggregate function. Post as the answer and I'll mark it as so?

Comment: I have posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DAX search for aggregation, can you please try this below where you directly referred to the column name:

```
min(table_a_Historical[exempt_status_cy])
```

Hopefully this will work.